# Linear Independence for Column Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the problem I'm struggling with:

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $B$ be an $n \times m$ matrix ($n \neq m$).  We are given that $AB = I_m$.

Are the column vectors of $A$ linearly independent or linearly dependent?  What about $B$?

Really lost on this one, so any help much appreciated!

Comment: If Im is the identity matrix and if $m=n$, then this means that $A^{-1}$ exists and that $A^{-1}=B$. If an inverse to a matrix exists, what does that mean about the column vectors?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that m != n

Comment: Deleted my post, because it was not helpful -- the columns of $A$ will be linearly dependent, and of $B$ independent.  Now, how to show this is the case?

Comment: Hmm @JeffSnider, this is what I'm stuck on.  Any hint here?

Comment: I think the answer from @sas is sufficient.  Do you need more detail, or a different approach?

Comment: I suppose, although we haven't seen the theorem about rank that he states, which makes me think there's another approach

Answer (score 2):

$\text{rank}\,AB\leq\min\{\text{rank}\,A,\text{rank}\,B\}$, then $\text{rank}\,A\leq\min\{m,n\}$ and $\text{rank}\,B\leq\min\{m,n\}$.

So, suppose $m>n$. That means $\text{rank}\,AB\leq n$ which is not possible, because $AB=I_m$ and $\text{rank}\,I_m=m$.

If $m<n$, $\text{rank}\,AB=m$ and $\text{rank}\,A\leq m$ tells us, that $\text{rank}\,A = m$.
The same for $B$, $\text{rank}\,B = m$.
But $A$ has $n$ columns and $B$ has precisely $m$ columns, so columns of $A$ are dependent and of $B$ are independent.

Comment: Note if $m<n$ then the columns of $A$ have to be linearly dependent because it is a set of $n>m$ columns in $\mathbb{R}^m$. 

But for your first case, if $m>n$, then this may still be OK since we are only looking for independence for the columns of $A$. See, for instance, the example Jeff Snider posted below.

Comment: @Darrin, it can't be true for $m>n$ that $AB=I_m$.

Comment: @Darrin still a bit confused here.  So rank(AB) = rank(Im) = m.  I'm with you so far.  But why does this imply A's col vectors are lin. dep. but B's are lin. indep.?

Comment: $\text{rank}B=m$ — do you agree? This means, there actually are $m$ linearly independent columns. And there are $m$ of them in $B$. And $\text{rank}A=m$ and there are only $m$ linearly independent columns, but there are $n$ of them in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Mariogs, I would now agree with what sas said.